# Database Design for table to summarize multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

My database has multiple tables that store user information

- users (user_id, name, email, phone, dob, picture)

All other profile details are in differnt tables with user_id as foreign key

- profile_work (one-to-many)
- profile_education (one-to-many)
- profile_emails (one-to-many)
- profile_locations (one-to-many)

There are 4 other similar tables.

My application requires details of users together so I send array of user_id's  as input to and it returns complete profile details of all users as a Json object.

As writes to user profile are very less and processing speed is very important for the app, I am planning to create another table that combines all the data of user and stores it. I would update this table everytime any of the profile table changes. I would use this table to fetch the data of about 25 users at a time.

How should the design of new table be?

> | user_id| name | email | picture | basic | work | education |

with json data in each of these coloumns (work & education)

or

> | user_id | json |

compiling everything as json and inserting in a table

Some of my services require only name, email and picture While others require work and education also.

What are the issues I would need to think through/ expect in future.

Other info

1. I am using mysql
2. My Db currently has 100K profiles
3. Expecting the db to reach about 1 Mn profiles in about a year, but will need to be scalable in future.

Comment: 1. Is the json going to be searched with?

2. How big is an average row entry look like?

Comment: nope, it will not be searched with, but we may need to select only a few entries sometimes... average size would be about 10 key value paris, normal text. (non-paragraph)

Comment: Make it a CSV instead of json. along with some meta like created, updated timestamps. Good to go